# why doesn't selenium see objects in my db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

given

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "visit '/'" do
  context "displays ", :driver => :selenium do
    before :each do
      FactoryGirl.create :restaurant, name: "John's Cafe"
      visit '/'
    end
    context "content:" do
      it "Restaurantly Spots!" do
        expect(page).to have_content 'Restaurantly Spots!'
      end

      it "John's Cafe" do
        expect(page).to have_content "John's Cafe"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

capybara test using selenium is failing for 'have_content' "John's Cafe".

Is capybara not able to see db objects that were added to db in before block?

I'm certain that the test db has the object in it, but it isn't getting displayed on the view page, the view page is wired correctly in development, I'm more curious why this test won't pass.  Thanks.

my test suite is configured based on avdi's blog post
http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could try:
a) Add the 'pry' gem to your gemfile and then you can add a binding.pry to your test code.  For example:

```
it "John's Cafe" do
  binding.pry
  expect(page).to have_content "John's Cafe"
end
```

At this point when you run the test you will see a console (like irb or rails console) and have introspection to your application.  So you can see if the content is in the database or not.  For example:

```
Restaurant.last
```

That should give you a clue as to if the restaurant is getting saved to the database.

One question, does the first test pass? "Restaurantly Spots!"?

Let me know if this works or you have more questions.

Mike Riley

Comment: One other thing you may want to extract your FactoryGirl.create out of the before do.  You could do:

     let(:restaurant) { FactoryGirl.create :restaurant, name: "John's Cafe" }

Above the before do

Comment: I tried both of those already @mike pry indicated that the db had the record correctly saved in it.  i'm not sure, i ended up going with a slightly different test structure where I'm creating the objects through browser interaction and it seems to be working.  thanks !